# Disabling widget margins post ICS

Tags: android, android-appwidget

It is well known to developers of Android app widgets that Android 4.0+ [imposes margins](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html) around the widget:

> Note: As of Android 4.0, app widgets are automatically given margins
>       between the widget frame and the app widget's bounding box to provide
>       better alignment with other widgets and icons on the user's home screen.

For me, and I'm sure [many others](http://radleymarx.com/blog/app-widget-padding-margins-in-ics-android/), this is unfortunate.  Screen space is particularly limited in a widget, so it is frustrating that so much of it is wasted.

I've done quite a lot of searching around for a way of disabling the padding.  Usually when there is an issue such as this, someone out there will have devised a cunning solution or workaround, and I'm really surprised that there doesn't seem to be one.  Or maybe my searching skills are not up to scratch.

But I'm also aware that custom launchers such as [Nova](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en_GB) allow you to disable the widget margins, so it is possible at some level, but probably custom launchers work at a much lower level that the average app or widget.

Has anyone come across a way (other than installing a custom launcher) of disabling widget margins, however kludgy?

Thanks.